# AWS EC2 External IP keeps changing on reboot, causing DNS problems

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Every time I restart my AWS EC2 instance, I get a new external IP, which causes my DNS to stop working. As a result I need to login to Route53, access my Hosted zone, and update the A records for the server.

How can I avoid having to update my A records each time?

Comment: are u using a static IP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. You cannot assign a static external IP, so you need to use an Elastic IP (which can be considered a static IP):

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-instance-addressing.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html

In the AWS console Select `Elastic IPs` on the left >> `Allocate new address`, follow the prompts. Then Right click and associate with your EC2 instance. Following this, update your Route53 records.